# noobie trying to install packages on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, raspbian-wheezy, packages

I'm trying to install the list of packages defined in step one here: 
http://raspberrypipbx.blogspot.ca/

The command I'm using looks like

```
pi@jl-raspberrypi / $ sudo apt-get install autoconf automake gawk g++ git-core libjpeg62-dev libncurses5-dev libtool make python-dev gawk pkg-config  libperl-dev libgdbm-dev libdb-dev libssl-dev
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python

Package autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libtool is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package automake
E: Unable to locate package gawk
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg62-dev
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5-dev
E: Package 'libtool' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package gawk
E: Unable to locate package libperl-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgdbm-dev
E: Unable to locate package libdb-dev
E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev
```

This is what my sources.list file looks like:

```
pi@jl-raspberrypi / $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://repo.pouf.org/raspbian/ wheezy main
pi@jl-raspberrypi / $
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This sometimes happens when your Pi's repositories haven't been updated.

Comment: I found I also had to do a 'sudo apt-get upgrade' to support the apt-get install libssl-dev